# In grails need to change a field in a domain class to nullable after I have already gone to production

Tags: sql, grails, null, nullable, alter-table

I have a domain class with a string field that I am changing to nullable.  In DataSource.groovy I have the mode set to "update."  Is there any way to make grails alter the MySql without changing to "create" or "create-drop."  I need the data in the MySql.

Follow up question:  I can do this change by hand with the line "ALTER TABLE myProject_my_domain_class MODIFY the_string varchar(20) NULL;"  Is this acceptable practice?  Also I have the same problem with a field linking to another domain class:

```
class myDomainClass {
  MyOtherDomainClass otherThing
}
```

changing to

```
class myDomainClass {
  MyOtherDomainClass otherThing
  static constraints = {
    otherThing(nullable:true)
  }
}
```

If the manual SQL ALTER is the only way, what is the correct way to write the SQL command so that I preserve the Key index between domain classes?

Comment: It seems that if I just do "ALTER TABLE myProejct_my_domain_class MODIFY other_thing_id bigint(20) NULL;" nothing breaks.  Would still like to know if I am using the Datasource.groovy wrong or some other n00bsauce answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Database Migration Plugin?

http://www.grails.org/plugin/database-migration

The process of using it is a bit more manual than just setting dbCreate="update", but it gives you much greater control, and it picks up on changes like making a column nullable. In addition, you can check even your small schema changes into your version control system, so you have a record of the changes that you make.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or something, the documentation on that page seems a little sparse even for the Grails wiki...

Comment: Try http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/index.html